# VBA random function problem - not working when closing workfile

Tags: excel, vba, random

I made a code generator with random function, but it generates the same codes when closing and opening the macro again. When running macro more times on 1 opening, it works fine but when I close the file with macro, open again, It generates the same codes. It is something like this - example:

1. open excel file, generated: 1111, generated: 2222, close
2. open file with macro, generated: 1111, generated 2222, generated 3333 close worksheet
3. Open file, generated: 1111

   ```
     For i = 15 To 38
     ws2.Cells(i, 2) = Int((9999 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
     ws2.Cells(i, 3) = Int((9999 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
     ws2.Cells(i, 4) = Int((9999 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
     ws2.Cells(i, 5) = Int((9999 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
     ws2.Cells(i, 6) = Int((9999 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
     ws2.Cells(i, 7) = Int((9999 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
     ws2.Cells(i, 8) = Int((9999 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
     ws2.Cells(i, 9) = Int((9999 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
     ws2.Cells(i, 10) = Int((9999 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
     ws2.Cells(i, 11) = Int((9999 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
     ws2.Cells(i, 12) = Int((9999 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)
     ws2.Cells(i, 13) = Int((9999 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)

     Next i
   ```

Expected result (example):

1. open file, generate: 1111, generate: 2222, close
2. open file with macor, generated: 3333, generated 4444, generated 5555 close worksheet
3. Open file, generated: 6666

Comment: Just a note: You don't need to have 12 (almost) identical lines of code, you could simply wrap `ws2.Cells(i, j) = Int((9999 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)` in a `For` loop: `For j = 2 To 13`. Also: I might be missing something, but the `- 0` and `+ 0` don't achieve anything as far as I can tell.

Comment: This formula is like `10000 * Rnd` so it should bring you different values if you have automatic calculation on. What is missing? Are you saving? Have you got automatic calculation?

Comment: Add [Randomize](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/randomize-statement) before the loop.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with protection when I think about it, but not sure how. Calculations are set to automatic

Comment: Have you tried `WorksheetFunction.RandBetween`?

Answer (score 2):

Add [Randomize](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/randomize-statement) before the loop. – BrakNicku

You don't need to have 12 (almost) identical lines of code, you could simply wrap ws2.Cells(i, j) = Int((9999 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0) in a For loop: For j = 2 To 13. Also: I might be missing something, but the - 0 and + 0 don't achieve anything as far as I can tell. – M.Schalk

```
Randomize
For i = 15 To 38
    For j = 2 To 13
        ws2.Cells(i, j) = Int(10000 * Rnd)
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

The VBA `Rnd` function [does not return a true random number](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/rnd.php) as the randomisation is based upon a seed number sequence which can repeat every time a file is opened, as you already experienced. As per the comments, the `WorksheetFunction.RandBetween` does not have such a drawback, and would work as a replacement in this case. Also as excel is aware of this, the `Randomize` function was added to randomise the seed number to get a more random number.

You've found this out from the comments already, however I'm still sending my answer as your code is extremely inefficient and could take a long time to run (it took me half a minute to open the file when testing). And I simply could not ignore that. Therefore I changed it to generate all your numbers within an array instead, and pasting that to your sheet after. This makes the code near-instant:

```
Private Sub workbook_Open()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim arr(0 To 24, 0 To 12) As Variant
For i = 0 To 24
    For j = 0 To 12
        Randomize
        arr(i, j) = Int(10000 * Rnd) 'WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)
    Next j
Next i
Range("B15:M38") = arr

End Sub
```